# Connecting to MS SQL Server from OSX using ActualODBC

Tags: sql, macos, qt, odbc

I'm developing a cross platform (windows + OSX) application that will be used commercially. The application will need to be able to access a database (MS SQL) and show the data.

I have installed the ActualODBC trial and use the following code to connect to the server:

```
QString connectionTemplate = "DRIVER={Actual SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;";
QString connectionString = connectionTemplate.arg("192.168.1.5").arg("Clients");

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

db.setDatabaseName( connectionString );
db.setUserName( "sa" );
db.setPassword( "password" );

if( db.open() )
{
    QMessageBox::about( this, tr("Connection"), tr("Connected :)") );
}
```

however I get the error QODBC3: Unable to connect.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was just some settings that I needed to change with the Actual SQL Server drivers!